# Hierarchical forecasting of time series including missing values (R)

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, hierarchical, forecast

I am trying to forecast a hierarchical time series including missing values.

I expect the same behavior like auto.arima for a single time series.
The missing values should not influence the result and also not be displayed.

```
fit = ts %>% auto.arima() 
forecast(fit, h=20) %>% autoplot()
```

[image]

But when I try to forecast the hierarchical time series, the NAs are automatically replaced by 0.
This influences the results dramatically. 
Both of the following functions have the same output:

```
hts_fc <- forecast(object = hts
                   , h = 20
                   , fmethod = "arima"                
)

hts_fc <- forecast(object = hts
                   , h = 20
                   , FUN = auto.arima
)

plot(hts_fc)
```

[image]

Comment: I think in order to reconcile you need a complete matrix, this is just an artifact of said matrix

Comment: You mean there is no solution for my problem, because matrix calculations do not work including NAs? Therefore, I would have to interpolate my input data first?

Comment: Not necessarily you just need to decide, if you think the data in this instance is zero let the default handle it, if you think this is just a collection problem interpolation may be necessary